# Session variable Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can't figure out how to resolve this InvalidCastException. The following code is throwing the exception.

```
data = (List<ReportDetails)Session["Grps"];
```

data is of type `List<ReportDetails>`.

I've tried

```
data = ((List<ReportDetails)Session["Grps"].ToList();
```

and

```
data = ((List<ReportDetails)Session["Grps"].Cast<ReportDetails>().ToList();
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please add the full exception?

Comment: Please post the code which sets `Session["Grps"]` as well. You may have to do `ToList()` on the data before putting it into `Session["Grps"]`.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[x.x.DataModel.ReportDetails_Result,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[x.x.DataModel.ReportDetails_Result]'.

Comment: Thank you @shankalpesh that was it!